# grep date from 2nd line of a text file

Tags: scripts

I have text file named (document_determinationv1.txt). This text file contains two lines which is mentioned below. I want to get the date(20210805) from the second line and want to store in a variable using shell script commands. I am new to Linux. Thanks in advance.

```
[DOCUMENT_DETERMINATION]
#REVISION:v1;DATE:20210805
```

Comment: [DOCUMENT_DETERMINATION]

Answer (score 2):

As always, there's more than one way to do it, depending on the exact requirements.

As one of the simplest ways, you could do:

```
AVARIABLE=$(sed -ne 's/.*DATE://p' document_determinationv1.txt)
```

This doesn't actually care *which* line the date is on. It will work as long as your file contains exactly one line containing the keyword DATE followed by a colon and the date you want to extract. It will also not check whether DATE appears as a word of its own, whether the part after DATE: is actually a date, or whether it is followed by any additional junk. If your file contains more than one line containing DATE followed by a colon then it will put all of the parts after each DATE: into the variable, separated by newlines, which may or may not wreak havoc with your further processing. So if your file contains, for example:

```
[DOCUMENT_DETERMINATION]
#REVISION:v1;DATE:20210805;WEIGHT:123kg
[REAL_DETERMINATION]
#PRIME:13;CANDIDATE:BART SIMPSON
```

then the command will happily put

```
20210805;WEIGHT:123kg
BART SIMPSON
```

into the variable, including the newline between the letters g and B.

But as long as you can guarantee the file has exactly the format you quoted in your question it will work fine.

Comment: Of course you can easily make it care which line it is on - by changing `s` to `2s` for example

Comment: It worked with this command what u provided.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
cat file.txt | sed "2q;d" | awk -F: '{print $3}'
```

- `cat` prints out the file content into a pipe
- `sed` takes this pipe and outputs the second line
- which `awk` takes, splits by colons and finally prints the third argument

You can try each command separately.
And if you want to store the whole stuff into a variable, use the `$(command)` syntax:

```
VAR=$(cat file.txt | sed "2q;d" | awk -F: '{print $3}')
```

And print the result:

```
echo $VAR
```

Comment: You don't need `cat`, and you don't need sed if you use awk's `NR` to choose the line ex. `awk -F'[;:]' 'NR==2 {print $4}' document_determinationv1.txt`